# ORMLite dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE doesn't work

Tags: java, android, serialization, ormlite

I have declared my type to be `SERIALIZABLE` as specified by ORMLite documentation, but I still get:

> ORMLite can't store unknown class interface java.io.Serializable for field 'task_titles'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE

My code looks like this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE) 
private Serializable task_titles;

public User() {
    task_titles = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I also tried using since ArrayList is serializable but without luck.

```
private ArrayList<String> task_titles;
```

For other reasons (limitations in applications outside my control), it is not a good option in this case to create another table containing the task titles.  Here's the full exception:

```
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lemonhat.snote/lemonhat.snote.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create RuntimeExcepitionDao for class class lemonhat.snote.db.User
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
...
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create RuntimeExcepitionDao for class class lemonhat.snote.db.User
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getRuntimeExceptionDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:260)
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at lemonhat.snote.db.DatabaseHelper.getUserDataDao(DatabaseHelper.java:109)
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at lemonhat.snote.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
...
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite can't store unknown class interface java.io.Serializable for field 'sort_order_of_lists'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.<init>(FieldType.java:183)
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
02-13 21:07:12.593: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:151)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ORMLite can't store unknown class interface java.io.Serializable for field 'sort_order_of_lists'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE

Am I missing something?  This error is talking about the field `sort_order_of_lists` but you are showing another field:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE) 
private Serializable task_titles;
```

I suspect that the `sort_order_of_lists` is missing the `dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE` annotation field.  Is that field in a base class?

If that is not the problem then I suspect you are using the table-config feature for Android and you need to re-generate the table-config because it is out of sync with your objects.  See the link for more details on this feature:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config

Comment: Ah, sorry, I showed task_titles because it was shorter to type. The error happened on my laptop which did not have Internet connection when I wrote the post, so I typed it on another computer. The same error happens for task_titles as for sort_order_of_lists. They are both ArrayList<String>

Comment: Yes, I might be defining it wrong actually. I update it manually but I just saw in the docs that there is a way to autogenerate it. I will try it when I get home.

Comment: I've updated my answer and put the link to the table-config docs which show how to generate it from a utility @Furstan88.